# integrability functions

Tags: calculus, integration

i couldn't solve this questions. could you help me please?

1)f is defined in [0,1] so f(0)=0 and $f(x)=\frac {1}{10^n}$ for $n=0,1,2,...,\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} < x \le \frac{1}{2^n}$. show that f is integrable in [0,1] and calculate $\int _0 ^1 f(x)dx$ . (i've spent hours on this one and i'm frustrated. according to Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem, for a function to be integrable it should be bounded and continuous almost everywhere. from the question it can be seen that x is bounded between $\frac{1}{2^n+1} < x \le \frac{1}{2^n}$ but i don't know how to prove if it's continuous - or is there a smarter way to prove it and calculate $\int _0 ^1 f(x)dx$.

2)f(x) is a continuous function in $[0,\infty)$ that applies $\int _0 ^ {x^2(1+x)}f(t)dt$ for every x>0. calculate f(2). (f(x) is continuous in $[0,\infty)$ and is bounded, but i don't know how to use the relation between f(t) and f(x) to calculate f(2).

hope you can help in with these, as i'm totally lost and frustrated.

Comment: The integral for question 2 is incomplete.

Comment: fixed it. thank you very much!

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "applies $\int_{0}^{x^2}(1+x) f(t)dt$ for every $x > 0$". Do you mean that $f(x) = \int_0^{x^2(1+x)} f(t)dt$?

Comment: i am having the same trouble. in the question it writes $\int _0 ^{x^2(1+x)} f(t)dt=x$ for every x>0. maybe because it's written "for every x>0" they mean that x is the function of x? i don't know how to approach it

Comment: could you write your answer as if it was written $\int_0 ^{x2(1+x)}f(t)dt=f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the first question.

Of course $f(x)$ is bounded, since it's values can only be of the form $10^{-n}$ for $n \geq 0$, so $ 0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$.

Note that $f$ would be a step function, except for the fact that there are infinitely many steps. But we can take care of this.

To show that $f$ is Riemann integrable, it's enough to show that we can sandwich it between two step functions, which are definitely integrable. Then, these step functions would have integrals which converge to the same point.

The first step function set would look as follows : $S_n(x) = f(x) $,for $x \geq \frac 1{2^{n+1}}$, and zero before that. Similarly, $T_n(x) = f(x)$, for $x \geq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, and $1$ before that.

So, we  have step functions $S_n$ and $T_n$ such that $S_n \leq f \leq T_n$. Now, I leave you to see that $S_n$ and $T_n$ have a Riemann integral which converge to the same number as $n \to \infty$. By definition, this would be the integral of $f$ as well.

EDIT : You are saying that the question is:$\int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)}f(t)dt = x$ for all $x > 0$. I think they mean that $x$, as a function of $x$, is the right hand side.

Define $g(y) = \int_0^y f(t)dt$. Then, we want to find $g(x^2(1+x)) = x$ for all $x$. Differentiating, we get $g'(x^2(1+x))(2x + 3x^2) = 1$, so $g'(x^2+x^3) = \frac{1}{2x+3x^2}$. However, note that $g'(x^2(1+x)) = f(x^2(1+x))$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Therefore, it follows  that $f(x^2(1+x)) = \frac 1{2x+3x^2}$ for all $x$. Now, see that $1^2(1+1) = 2$, so putting $x=1$ in this statement, $f(2) = \frac{1}{2+3} = \frac 15$.

Comment: thank you very much. could you please help me with the second one? $\int_0 ^{x2(1+x)}f(t)dt=f(x)$?

Comment: Ok, I see! Fine, I will attempt this question in an edit. I will get back to you once I am done.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: I request you to accept the answer and close the question, since it has been answered. If you like, you can wait for other answers though.